# Default UITableViewCell state

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I created a custom UITableViewRowAction. So if I swipe to the left over a UITableViewCell a custom button comes up (none custom button is for example a delete button). If I press this custom button, a UIView comes up but the button which was pressed is still presented. I'd like to see the UITableViewCell without this button after it has been pressed. Does someone of you knows how to do this in Swift and would like to help me? Thanks for your answers.

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8g04kcvswujsn71/stackQuestion.png?dl=0

Comment: Difficult to understand your question. Reword, add some code, maybe a screenshot. e.g. Not sure what you mean by "the button which was pressed is always presented"

Comment: Ok. I updated my question with a screenshot. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

I use [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) to achieve those actions in my own apps.  Give it a look its great!

You can use this class like this:

**1. Import The SWTableViewCell Classes**

Follow the link above or simply search for SWTableViewCell on github.  Download the zip (or use cocoa pods, if you are familiar with them).

Open the unzipped directory and find the PodsFile directory.  Drag the contents of this directory into your project. Doing this should cause Xcode to ask to create the bridging header.  Agree to it and then add

```
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"
```

to that bridging header file.  If you compile you will get some *Parse issue errors: expected type*.  To fix these simply add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

to NSMutableArray+SWUtilityButtons.h.  Now we are ready to rock and roll.

**2. Create An SWTableViewCell Subclass**

OK, you could use the cell as is, but most likely you would like to spiff up the cell beyond the simple default cell looks.  If so create a new cocoa touch class (in swift) and make your cell a subclass of `SWTableViewCell`.  It should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class MySWCell: SWTableViewCell {

}
```

If you are using storyboard you can make your cells in your tableview of this class, hook up any outlets/actions etc.  All the lovely things you need to do to make the cell just like you need it.

**3. Use Your Subclass In a TableView**

For this example I just started with the Master-Detail base project.  You change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to use your new custom cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MySWCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description  
    return cell
}
```

While this is great, you probably want to add right/left utility buttons, it is the reason we are doing all of this:

**4. Add the Utility Buttons**

You can do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but prefer to put this in a separate function:

```
func getRightUtilityButtonsToCell()-> NSMutableArray{
    var utilityButtons: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    utilityButtons.sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), title: NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment: ""))
    utilityButtons.sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor(UIColor.blueColor(), title: NSLocalizedString("Email", comment: ""))
    return utilityButtons
}
```

Now use this method in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.rightUtilityButtons = self.getRightUtilityButtons();
```

If you were to swipe left on the cell, you would have two buttons:

[image: What it should look like]

However, these buttons don't do very much.  We need to conform to the delegate.

**5. Respond The Buttons**

First, tell the cell that you are its delegate.  Again, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add this line:

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

Then adjust the class definition to this:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, SWTableViewCellDelegate
```

`MasterViewController` will be replaced with the name of the class you have handling your tableview datasource/delegate.

Now implement the `didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex` function:

```
func swipeableTableViewCell(cell: SWTableViewCell!, didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex index: Int) {
    if index == 0 {
        println("delete button")
    }else {
        println("print button")
    }
}
```

Now you are set to go!  You can also tell the cell to do cool things like hide the buttons after one is selected using the `hideUtilityButtonsAnimated` method inside of the `didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex` method:

```
cell.hideUtilityButtonsAnimated(true);
```

This function will hide the cells when the tableview scrolls:

```
func swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe(cell: SWTableViewCell!) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Have fun, its a great set of classes!

Comment: But it's written in Objective-C.

Comment: Just put it in the bridging header and you can interact with the library in swift.

Comment: And how can I find out if a button has been pressed?

Comment: implement the delegate method - (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;

Comment: The README.md file for this repository is pretty good: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/blob/master/README.md

Comment: In swift it would be something like this     func swipeableTableViewCell(cell: SWTableViewCell!, didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex index: Int) {}

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ScottThompson: I did, but I also provided the link so that he could familiarize himself with the rest of the class usage. But I could also show him how to use the class in an example, perhaps that is what you meant. I'll update the answer.